# Average value of 3 measurements

Tags: homework-and-exercises, measurement-problem

Some physical quantity was measured two times. It’s average value is equal to 5. The reading of the third measurement is equal to 2. What is the average value based on the results of three measurements

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To find the average value based on the results of three measurements, you need to calculate the average of the three values. In this case, the average value of the first two measurements is 5, and the third measurement has a value of 2. Therefore, the average of all three measurements is:

(5 + 5 + 2) / 3 = 4

Answer (score 0):

Good question ! You can use recursive averaging procedure when previous measurement values are lost and just previous average value remains :
$$ \overline x_n = \left(1−\frac 1n\right)\overline x_{n−1} + \frac 1n x_n \tag 1$$

Substituting your given data, gives:

$$ \overline x_3 = (1−1/3)×5 + (1/3)×2 = 4 \tag 2$$